# Avoid overlapping of Widgets in QVBoxLayout

Tags: qt, qwidget, overlapping, qvboxlayout

I tried to dynamically add more fields to select multiple paths in my application. Unfortunaley I am not able to get rid of the overlap that some icons have:

[image]

I add them with the following code:

```
void SettingsDialog::addPathEdit(QString dir)
{
    if (amountPaths > maxAmountPaths) {
        showError(tr("Cannot add more than %1 paths").arg(maxAmountPaths));
        return;
    }
    QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    hLayout->setObjectName("pathLine");
    hLayout->setSizeConstraint(QHBoxLayout::SetMinimumSize);

    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(dir);
    lineEdit->setMinimumHeight(25);
    lineEdit->setObjectName("path");
    hLayout->addWidget(lineEdit);

    QPushButton *browseButton = new QPushButton(tr("Browse..."));
    browseButton->setMinimumHeight(25);
    browseButton->setObjectName("browseButton");
    hLayout->addWidget(browseButton);
    connect(browseButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_browse_button_clicked()));

    ui->pathHolderLayout->addLayout(hLayout);
    amountPaths++;
}
```

where `pathHolderLayout` is a QVBoxLayout.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This usually means that the layout constraints are not correctly pushed up the hierarchy up to the dialog. Could you create a minimal working example of your issue?

Comment: @E4z9 You can find the whole source code [here](https://github.com/minils/EasySlideshow).

Comment: as a side comment, you should get rid of the `findChildren<QPushButton *>("browseButton")` et al, by using lambdas/C++11: In addPathEdit do `connect(browseButton, &QPushButton::clicked, lineEdit, [this,lineEdit]() { this->on_browse_button_clicked(lineEdit); })` and change the "slot" to get the line edit as a argument: `void SettingsDialog::on_browse_button_clicked(QLineEdit *lineEdit)`

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211878/how-to-reference-dynamically-created-label-when-the-button-next-to-it-is-clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layouts in Qt have a "[size constraint](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#sizeConstraint-prop)" which defines the minimumSize/maximumSize/sizeHint of the layout, depending on the minimumSize/maximumSize/sizeHint of their contents.

The default size constraint is `QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint`, defined as "The main widget's minimum size is set to minimumSize(), *unless the widget already has a minimum size*."

Your top-level layout (of the dialog) has the default size constraint (in the .ui file), and you set a minimum size for the dialog (in the .ui file), so the constraint effectively does nothing at all.

To fix your issue you either have to remove the minimum size of the dialog (e.g. select the value of property the .ui editor and click the back arrow), or set the size constraint of the top-level layout to `QLayout::SetMinimumSize`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand for which layout I needed to set this property. But now it's clear.