# How to reference dynamically created label when the button next to it is clicked [Qt]

Tags: c++, qt

Each time the "Add Client" button is pressed - a minus button, the name of the client, a counter for the client and a plus button are added in a horizontal line to the gridLayout. I want to update the count (QLabel) when the plus/minus button is pressed.

Here is my code:

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>

int row = 0;

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QPushButton* minus_button = new QPushButton();
    QPushButton* plus_button = new QPushButton();
    minus_button->setText("-");
    plus_button->setText("+");

    QLabel* client_name = new QLabel(ui->lineEdit->text(), this);
    QLabel* client_count = new QLabel("", this);

    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(minus_button, row, 1, Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignHCenter);
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(client_name, row, 2, Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignHCenter);
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(client_count, row, 3, Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignHCenter);
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(plus_button, row++, 4, Qt::AlignTop|Qt::AlignHCenter);

    connect(minus_button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(minusCount()));
    connect(plus_button, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(plusCount()));
}

void Widget::minusCount(){
    //Here I want to somehow reference the client_count label which is in the same row
}
void Widget::plusCount(){
    //Here I want to somehow reference the client_count label which is in the same row
}
```

EDIT: After Kevin's comment, here is the working code for anyone who may need it.

```
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QSignalMapper>

QSignalMapper* m_minusMapper;
QSignalMapper* m_plusMapper;

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    m_minusMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    connect(m_minusMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), this, SLOT(minusCount(QWidget*)));

    m_plusMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
    connect(m_plusMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), this, SLOT(plusCount(QWidget*)));
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QPushButton* minus_button = new QPushButton();
    minus_button->setObjectName("minus" + QString::number(row));
    minus_button->setText("-");

    QPushButton* plus_button = new QPushButton();
    plus_button->setObjectName("plus" + QString::number(row));
    plus_button->setText("+");

    QLabel* client_name = new QLabel(ui->lineEdit->text(), this);
    QLabel* client_count = new QLabel("0", this);

    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(minus_button, row, 1, Qt::AlignVCenter|Qt::AlignHCenter);
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(client_name, row, 2, Qt::AlignVCenter|Qt::AlignHCenter);
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(client_count, row, 3, Qt::AlignVCenter|Qt::AlignHCenter);
    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(plus_button, row++, 4, Qt::AlignVCenter|Qt::AlignHCenter);

    connect(minus_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), m_minusMapper, SLOT(map()));
    connect(plus_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), m_plusMapper, SLOT(map()));

    m_minusMapper->setMapping(minus_button, client_count);
    m_plusMapper->setMapping(plus_button, client_count);
}

void Widget::minusCount(QWidget *widget)
{
    QLabel *client_count = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(widget);
    QString initCount = client_count->text();
    int newCount = initCount.toInt() - 1;
    client_count->setText(QString::number(newCount));
}

void Widget::plusCount(QWidget *widget)
{
    QLabel *client_count = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(widget);
    QString initCount = client_count->text();
    int newCount = initCount.toInt() + 1;
    client_count->setText(QString::number(newCount));
}
```

Comment: Easiest way is to store your widgets in some kind of member variable. Or you can access it via parent with `QObject::findChild`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kevin's answer in principle is fine, but since we've got 2016 now and MSVC2010, gcc 4.7, and Clang 3.1 (and possibly earlier versions) support lambdas/C++11, I'd like to add a version without QSignalMapper:

```
static void minusCount(QLabel *label)
{
    QString initCount = label->text();
    int newCount = initCount.toInt() - 1;
    label->setText(QString::number(newCount));
}

static void plusCount(QLabel *label)
{
    QString initCount = label->text();
    int newCount = initCount.toInt() + 1;
    label->setText(QString::number(newCount));
}

void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    // ... add the labels and buttons, then:
    connect(minus_button, &QPushButton::clicked,
            client_count, [client_count]() { minusCount(client_count); });
    connect(plus_button, &QPushButton::clicked,
            client_count, [client_count]() { plusCount(client_count); });
}
```

Here the `client_count` label that the button click should change is captured in the lambda, and directly passed to the function handling it.

The `minusCount` and `plusCount` also can be static functions then, since they only operate on the label that is passed as an argument, so they are independent from any `Widget` instance.

Comment: While this is true, I know way to many people who are stuck with VS2008 and similar aged environments to suggest any C++11/14 based solution by default :)

Comment: I don't doubt it, but on the other hand I've got the feeling from my filter-bubble that there are too many people who are _not_ stuck with aged environments, but are not very aware of the C++11 patterns anyhow ;) (the still not modernized Qt examples probably don't help in this regard...)

Comment: @kuba-ober How can I comment/discuss your edit? There is no need for capturing `this`, because minus/plusCount can be static now. (It would make sense to comment on that fact in the answer though.)

Comment: Making the count static is wrong, because it unnecessarily limits the UI to just one instance, and there's nothing in the question that details such desire. But feel free to revert the edit if you disagree, of course. It looked like an ommission to me, though.

Comment: @KubaOber Why would that limit the UI to just one instance? The static minus/plusCount methods get the label they operate on as an argument. There is nothing "UI instance" specific to them. Have a look at the `Widget::minusCount` and `Widget::plusCount` methods from obl's working code: There is nothing specific to the Widget instance in there, they only operate on the widget that is passed as an argument.

Comment: I've added some details on this to the answer

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a `QSignalMapper`

```
// in the constructor of your class
m_minusSignalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
connect(m_minusSignalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), this, SLOT(minusCount(QWidget*)));

m_plusSignalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
connect(m_plusSignalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QWidget*)), this, SLOT(plusCount(QWidget*)));


// in your button slot you connect to the respective mapper instead
connect(minus_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), m_minusMapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(plus_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), m_plusMapper, SLOT(map()));

// and you set up the mapping
m_minusMapper->setMapping(minus_button, client_count);
m_plusMapper->setMapping(plus_button, client_count);

// in the the two receiver slots, the argument is the label
void Widget::minusCount(QWidget *widget)
{
    QLabel *client_count = qobject_cast<QLabel*>(widget);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Here is the code after a little editing, you made a small typo by using m_minusMapper and m_minusSignalMapper.

Comment: EDIT: Thanks Kevin. I will edit my new code in. Your code worked perfectly, except you made a small typo by using m_minusMapper and m_minusSignalMapper.